# Android Studio Update 3.3.1 debugging breakpoints executing very slowly?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I have updated my Android Studio to version `3.3.1`, but now breakpoints are executing very slowly? First breakpoint take around 5 minutes to execute.

Can anyone please tell me what can I do to make it work like it was in the previous version?

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue when I installed android studio 3.3.2. Any time I'd try to debug my app, it would run crazily slow. But finally got the solution as described below:

1. Go to the debugger and select view breakpoints
2. Make sure the Java method Breakpoint is unchecked.

[image]

It's often easy to add method breakpoints accidentally and That's usually the main reason behind the significant slowness of the debugging speed.
Follow the few steps below if that the case:

Comment: can you share the reason for this slow performance after 3.3.1 release and how your solution works to make it fast... your solution would be more usable then

Comment: Hi @Ashu, The problem occurred when I shifted from Windows to MacOs. But I believe have has to do with the android Studio version.

Comment: yep it seems that android studio has changed how it debugs the applications... i can't find any such change documentation anywhere though. Before, it wouldn't be slow even with method breakpoints.

Answer (score -5):

just remove all breakup points in your android studio.then automatically android debug will be fast.

remove all breakpoint step:
go to debugger then select red button it will pop up all debugger break point and then remove.